# Round and round, what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

So I put this into the [Sandbox](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5446/29949), it got a few upvotes, but no comments. It may be rubbish (it's the only one I've produced), but might as well give it a punt:

---

> Round and round,
>   Driven by Man or horse.
>   An enemy of power,
>   Repeated throughout history.
>   Enjoyed with bacon and tea,
>   When I arrive, I change everything.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> a REVOLUTION.

*Round and round,*

> Revolution as in rotating.

*Driven by Man or horse.*

> Revolutions of components inside an engine? Man drives vehicles which were once pulled by horses and have output measured in horsepower.

*An enemy of power,*

> Revolution as in uprising.

*Repeated throughout history.*

> French Revolution, Russian Revolution, etc.

*Enjoyed with bacon and tea,*

> [Bacon's revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon's_Rebellion) and the [Boston Tea Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Tea_Party)?

*When I arrive, I change everything.*

> Revolutionary as in making big changes.

Comment: man, you *are* fast. Correct answer, Man or Horse clue is wrong. I'm cheating slightly, Man/Horse is actually two different clues on one line. The Bacon clue is correct, but not what I was thinking when I wrote it.

Comment: @Obsidian [Horse](http://hauteecole.ru/en/horse_revolution.php)? :-P

Comment: nope. Horse answer could be explosive...

Comment: Now you have it. ;) The man part was really just referencing your answer to the "enemy of power", but I like where you went with it. In terms of Bacon, I was actually thinking of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Bacon) Bacon